# Writing file on ext SD card (KITKAT)

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

My app records voice and a user complains that he is not able to save the recordings on the external SD card (android 4.4.2).

I know the problem with the KITKAT and I work to adjust this, but until then I want a workaround.

**I've instructed him to create a folder on ext. sd card: "extSDcard mount name"/Android/data/myAppPackage/files (using the PC connection) and then to go the app and select the recordings dir to point out to the location above** He's telling me isn't working this way...I wonder why, since the path is the app private one?

Is there any solution until I will came up with a new app update?

Comment: i have built a similar app..i dint find any issue saving the audio in sdcard..i used http://i-liger.com/sites/default/files/ExtAudioRecorder.java in my case...is he complaining about any specific device ?

Comment: @vny Kumar - on devices running android 4.4 and above it will fail to save/write files on external SD card(not the built in SD). The only path you can store files is the app private one. See writing files doc on Android site

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html  there is a mention about Android 4.4